# Minecraft - Command for founding block placed on gamemode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

is in Minecraft existing command for founding block placed on gamemode or can i use command /testforblock with writen specification ? If this possible hot can i do this ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you asking if you can check for a block you have (for example) placed in creative? If so, I don't think there is any way to detect what blocks were placed in which gamemode.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, the data of who placed it is not stored in the block.

If the players haven't placed the block yet, you could possibly set something up to track what gamemode the person who placed the block was in. But if they've already placed the block, no.